# remover primeiro array de um array

Tags: php

tenho o seguinte array e gostaria de remover sempre o primeiro array, como possa fazer isso? obs: existe a possibilidade do primeiro array nem sempre ter o índice 0.

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => number
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 101010100
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 30303030
            )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Utilize o [`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-shift.php):

```
$arr  = [['number'], [101010100], [30303030]];

array_shift($arr);

print_r($arr);
```

Retornará:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 101010100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30303030
        )

)
```

Exemplo no [ideone](http://ideone.com/BvoYMj)

Comment: Eu tentei com essa função antes de fazer a pergunta, mas ele está deixando somente o primeiro array e remove o resto

Comment: Qual versão do `PHP` você está utilizando? Veja no [ideone](http://ideone.com/BvoYMj) o exemplo funcionando.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <?php
            $cars = array
                 (
                 array("Volvo",22,18),
                 array("BMW",15,13),
                 array("Saab",5,2),
                 array("Land Rover",17,15)
                 );
            array_shift($cars); //Retira o primeiro elemento do array
    ?>
```

Comment: Eu tentei com essa função antes de fazer a pergunta, mas ele está deixando somente o primeiro array e remove o resto

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar a função array_splice e remover uma parcela do array.

```
$novoArray = array_splice($array, 1);
```

Remove até a primeira posição e ajusta os índices.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score -1):

array_shift($cars); //Retira o primeiro elemento do array

está retornando apenas o primeiro elemento pois você esta atribuindo este array_shift ao $cars. provavelmente está fazendo $cars = array_shift($cars);
tente por o array_shift($cars) sozinho.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).